# How to import XNA types (and other types) in MS Visio?

Tags: c#, uml, types, xna, visio

I'm working on the UML of a game we will do in XNA, but Visio does not provide XNA types (like Vector3 or Model). For the moment, I replace those types by C#::Object but it's not really useful to understand...

Is there a way to import XNA types in Visio, or do I have to recreate them manually ?

Thanks

Altefquatre

Answer (score 0):

If you have visual studio professional or above, I believe it comes with a UML diagram tool that automatically includes all your classes and methods.